# import pymongo is failing in vs with Module not found error

Tags: python, pymongo

My import pymongo is failing in vs with Module not found error.
Code:
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()

Error:
import pymongo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymongo'

Pip install completed already:
pip install pymongo
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo

Are there any extensions needed in vs? The same code is executing fine in Jupyter notebook. Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe VS Code doesn't read from the correct Python virtual environment. Consider checking your set virtual environment at the bottom left corner.

[image]